# Glmer with nested random effect converges only sometimes

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have some data on the number of items on tree branches and want to model a regression to predict the number of items from the branch diameter and the position in the crown (in/out, top/mid/bot).

We sampled the branches so that we can use every sub-branch of each sampled branch as a separate data point with the same position in the crown but with a different number of items and a different branch diameter.

So I have data that looks like this:

```
   tree main_branch diameter_mm count_item crown_third crown_in_out
1  A    A           11          111        top         in
2  A    A           8           67         top         in
3  A    B           6           31         mid         out
4  A    B           7           73         mid         out
5  B    A           8           75         bot         in
6  B    B           6           42         top         out
```

As I have to deal with overdispersion and zero inflation as well, I made two models (binomial and negative binomial), one predicting whether there is an item on a branch. And a second model is how many items there are if there is an item.

So, I specified mixed effect models using the **lme4** package in R:

```
# yes/no
mod_bin <- glmer(item_yes_no ~ log(diameter_mm) + crown_in_out * crown_third + 
                 (1 | tree / main_branch), data = data_all, family = binomial())
    
# counts
mod_neg <- glmer.nb(count_item ~ log(diameter_mm) + crown_in_out * crown_third + 
                    (1 | tree / main_branch), data = no_zeros_all)
```

However, the models are apparently really unstable. Depending on the order of the categorical variables and whether I give them as character or factor, the model sometimes converges, sometimes not. I also removed 10% from the data for testing later on and train the model on the remaining 90%. Depending on the split, the model converges and sometimes doesn't. Overall, to me, it seems quite random whether it (a) converges, (b) has a singular fit, or (c) fails to converge. Also, sometimes the model needs the interaction to converge, or sometimes it can't converge with the interaction.

What can be the reasons for this instability? And how can I solve this issue? I don't feel comfortable using just one of the converging models without asking myself why the model, most of the time, does not converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The models you are trying to fit say that measurements within the same tree are correlated and that measurements in the same branch within a tree are more correlated than measurements from different branches in the tree. It may be that your data do not support these correlations, and a simpler structure is more appropriate, e.g.,

```r
# yes/no
mod_bin <- glmer(item_yes_no ~ log(diameter_mm) + crown_in_out * crown_third + 
                 (1 | tree), data = data_all, family = binomial())
    
# counts
mod_neg <- glmer.nb(count_item ~ log(diameter_mm) + crown_in_out * crown_third + 
                    (1 | tree), data = no_zeros_all)
```